# Comportamiento raro en Combobox c# Winform

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Tengo el siguiente problema cuando selecciono un valor de cualquier ComboBox(DropDownStyle : List), por alguna razon llama todos los eventos 'Selected Index Changed' de todos los ComboBox en el formulario, esto no tendría ningun problema pero al hacer seguimiento veo que todos los combobox copian el valor seleccionado index que escogi en un combobox, si escojo en el combobox1 el item que tiene index1 llama al evento del combobox1 y todo normal posterior a eso llama al evento del combobox2 y hace como si hubiera seleccionado el item que tiene index1 en el combobox2, cada combobox tiene su propio evento : SelectedIndexChanged.
El comportamiento normal sería escojer un valor en 1 combobox y que este llene valores en el combobox que está a su derecha.

He intentado borrar todos los combos y crealos nuevamente uno por uno pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo incluso con solo 2 combobox en el formulario.

Adjunto codigo de los eventos del Combobox 1 y 2.

```
/*Combobox1*/ 
   private void comboBox11_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                pDataSet = new DataSet();
                pDataSet.Clear();
                pDataSet = neProcesos.NeDataSetCajaCr(13, "", "", "", "", "");

                comboBox111.DataSource = pDataSet.Tables[0];
                comboBox111.DisplayMember = "Description";
                comboBox111.ValueMember = "ID";
                comboBox111.SelectedIndex = 0;

                if (comboBox11.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    pDataSet = new DataSet();
                    pDataSet.Clear();
                    pDataSet = neProcesos.NeDataSetCajaCr(14, comboBox11.SelectedValue.ToString(), "", "", "", "");

                    comboBox111.DataSource = pDataSet.Tables[0];
                    comboBox111.DisplayMember = "Description";
                    comboBox111.ValueMember = "ID";
                    comboBox111.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
```

```
/*ComboBox2*/
 private void comboBox12_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                pDataSet = new DataSet();
                pDataSet.Clear();
                pDataSet = neProcesos.NeDataSetCajaCr(13, "", "", "", "", "");

                comboBox121.DataSource = pDataSet.Tables[0];
                comboBox121.DisplayMember = "Description";
                comboBox121.ValueMember = "ID";
                comboBox121.SelectedIndex = 0;

                if (comboBox12.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    pDataSet = new DataSet();
                    pDataSet.Clear();
                    pDataSet = neProcesos.NeDataSetCajaCr(14, comboBox12.SelectedValue.ToString(), "", "", "", "");

                    comboBox121.DataSource = pDataSet.Tables[0];
                    comboBox121.DisplayMember = "Description";
                    comboBox121.ValueMember = "ID";
                    comboBox121.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
```

[image: Example Gif]

Comment: prueba usar el evento commitedchangedvalue en vez de selectedindex

Comment: Sucede lo mismo Japv , los combobox primarios cambian al index que seleccione en el Combobox1 mas no entra a su evento de llenar la data de los combos en la parte derecha

Comment: y tu tienes todos los combo enlazados al mismo bindingsource?

Comment: Todos los combos en un inicio van enlazados a una misma tabla exactamente , la cual trae los valores default que vez cuando selecciono uno de ellos en el primer combobox.

Comment: si todos van enlazados a la misma fuente de datos lo mas probable es que te suceda eso q dices, ya que todos los combo apuntan a la misma  fuente de datos

Comment: Amigo , eres un genio, todos los combos tenian de source un Dataset.tables[0]. Tras leer tu comentario hice que el sp que llena ese dataset regrese 14 tablas , y las asigne de 1 en 1 Dataset.tables[0]., dataset.tables[1]..etc ; y el problema fue solucionado! muchas graacias Japv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso te sucede porque tienes todos los **combobox** asociados a la misma fuente de datos, y al seleccionar un elemento en un **combobox**, todos los demás **combobox** apuntarán a ese mismo valor, en resumen los **comobobox** deben tener diferente fuente de datos.